# Spotify Authentication on MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Hi I am quite new to Swift and I am trying to make a MacOS app using Spotify's API. I need the user to authenticate their Spotify Account. There are many ways to do this on iOS apps but I can't seem to find how to do it with MacOS apps.

Should I learn a backend language to do this? Like Node JS and Python? Or is there a simple solution for my problem?

Comment: You can try to see [this](https://github.com/xzzz9097/SpotifyKit), I've never used it, it uses simple HTTP request.

Comment: @Kerberos Hey!! Thank you so much! It works!

Comment: You should use my library: https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPI. It takes care of the authorization process for you.